# The input object cannot be bound to any parameters?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set user extension properties from a powershell code with an input coming from a CSV file.

I'm getting this error:

> Set-AzureADUserExtension : The input object cannot be bound to any
> parameters for the command either because the command does not take
> pipeline  input or the input and its properties do not match any of
> the parameters that take pipeline input. At line:14 char:17
>
> - ...     $user | Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $upn -ExtensionName "e ...
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (class User {   ...Type: Member } :PSObject) [Set-AzureADUserExtension],
>   ParameterBindingException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Graph.PowerShell.Custom.SetAzureADUserExtension

I'm kind of new to this, so it's for sure not the best.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: have you read the error message? [*grin*] you need to answer the following --- _does the cmdlet in question accept pipeline input_?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for help you will need to share your code, not just the error.  I verified for you that Set-AzureADUserExtension does take pipeline input for all properties.
What I can't tell is where you set $UPN or why you are piping $user to the command since I can't see your code.